# Spring JPA – Multiple Databases with the same Repositories

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I have configured Spring JPA to work with multiple data sources following this example.
[Spring JPA – Multiple Databases](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)

It works as expected but since I want to use different data sources but with the same repositories there is an issue. When I try to use "Declarative Transaction Management" on my services and specify which transaction I am going to use the primary transaction or secondary one the transaction annotation is ignoring it. So in this case it is using the second one. However, both of the beans "PlatformTransactionManager" are created but when it comes to using in "@Transactional" I am not able to make the transaction work with the bean I have specified. So it seems that @Transactional is ignoring the bean name since they have the same repositories. Is there any way how can I use declarative transactions as I am trying to do it? As I have seen it can be done with Programmatic Transaction Management but it will cost me to change the whole code on my services since I have been using only declarative transactions.

Comment: and you tried `@Transactional( transactionManager = "yourtransactionName")` right?

Comment: @SMA yes, exactly but it is ignoring it and using always the second bean created.

Comment: I think the problem is related with Spring Aspect that is "triggered" by the annotations. You define for each "EntityManager" the packages (or classes) that he "owns". Since both of both EntityManagers refer to the same classes, when "discovery" kicks in, it will return only one of them. I think there is no solution for this problem. Why do you want 2 EntityManager that point to the same classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, it is better to have two separate microservices connecting to two different data sources.

Comment: The answer was found: It can be done by extending AbstractRoutingDataSource class of spring.

Comment: @javaprogramming can you show me your answer because i m facing the same issue..thanks

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we also have two databases, both using JPA and repositories. However, they do use different repositories, but I think our approach should also work in your case. We define an `EntityManagerFactory` and a `TransactionManager` per database. I cannot confirm this works, but I believe it should.

Primary Datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"ch.sac.data.primary.repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class ImporterPrimaryDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource(final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        return dataSourceProperties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public Flyway primaryFlyway(
            final DataSource dataSource,
            @Value("${spring.flyway.locations}") final String[] flywayLocations,
            @Value("${spring.flyway.validate-on-migrate:true}")
                    final boolean flywayValidateOnMigrate) {
        final var flyway =
                Flyway.configure()
                        .dataSource(dataSource)
                        .locations(flywayLocations)
                        .validateOnMigrate(flywayValidateOnMigrate)
                        .load();
        flyway.migrate();
        return flyway;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder,
            final DataSource dataSource) {

        final var jpaProperties =
                Map.ofEntries(
                        Map.entry(
                                "hibernate.dialect",
                                "org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"));

        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("ch.sac.model.primary.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("dataSource")
                .properties(jpaProperties)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Secondary Datasource (SQLite Database, created in-memory, adjust to your use-case):

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"ch.sac.data.sqlite.repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqliteEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "sqliteTransactionManager")
public class ImporterSQLiteDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "sqliteDBFilePath")
    public String sqliteDBFilePath() throws IOException {
        return TempFileManager.createEmptyTempFile("metadata.sqlite").toString();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqliteDataSourceProperties")
    public DataSourceProperties sqliteDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqliteDataSource")
    public DataSource sqliteDataSource(
            @Qualifier("sqliteDataSourceProperties")
                    final DataSourceProperties sqliteDataSourceProperties,
            final String sqliteDBFilePath) {
        return sqliteDataSourceProperties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .driverClassName("org.sqlite.JDBC")
                .url("jdbc:sqlite:" + sqliteDBFilePath)
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flyway sqliteFlyway(
            @Qualifier("sqliteDataSource") final DataSource sqliteDataSource,
            @Value("${sqlite.flyway.locations}") final String[] flywayLocations) {
        final var flyway =
                Flyway.configure().dataSource(sqliteDataSource).locations(flywayLocations).load();
        flyway.migrate();
        return flyway;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqliteEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqliteEntityManagerFactory(
            final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder sqliteEntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
            @Qualifier("sqliteDataSource") final DataSource sqliteDataSource) {

        final var sqliteJpaProperties =
                Map.ofEntries(
                        Map.entry(
                                "hibernate.dialect", "org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect"));

        return sqliteEntityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(sqliteDataSource)
                .packages("ch.sac.model.sqlite.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("sqliteDataSource")
                .properties(sqliteJpaProperties)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqliteTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager sqliteTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("sqliteEntityManagerFactory")
                    final EntityManagerFactory sqliteEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(sqliteEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right it should but it’s not working when in comes to use the same repositories. I have exactly the same configuration only that I am specifying the same repositories for both of databases.

Comment: As I said for both of datasources both of the beans are created “ EntityManagerFactory and TransactionManager” but with declarative transactions it is not working as expected. Even I specify to use primary transaction it will use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found: It can be done by extending AbstractRoutingDataSource class of spring.

Comment: Could you extend this answer please? Ideally with a code sample or reference to some documentation.

Comment: Can you up vote my answer if you got the answer from my response that is.

Comment: Long time but yes you were correct!